# Click on button from a dropdown menu VBA

Tags: html, excel, vba

I'm having issues clicking on a button from a dropdown menu. Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="dropdown text-center">
   <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
      <!-- react-text: 400 -->Process Path Group: <!-- /react-text --><!-- react-text: 401 -->ALL<!-- /react-text -->
   </button>
   <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="statusProcessPathGroupDropdown" style="left: 0px; top: 0px; position: absolute; transform: translate3d(206px, 37px, 0px);" x-placement="bottom-end"><button class="dropdown-item active" type="button">ALL</button><button class="dropdown-item" type="button">SINGLE</button><button class="dropdown-item" type="button">MULTI</button></div>
</div>
```

I want to click on the ALL button but I cannot get there to click on it. I tried everything. Here's the last try I have.

```
Sub Macro()
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
  Set IE = New InternetExplorerMedium
  url1 = "url1"

With IE
   .Visible = True
   .navigate url1


End With

Set AvailableLinks = IE.document.getElementByTagName("button")
        For Each cLink In AvailableLinks
            If cLink.innerHTML = "ALL" Then
            cLink.Click
            End If
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: There is no such thing as `.getElementByTagName()`.
The method you are looking for is `.getElementsByTagName()`, which returns a collection of html elements. Also, you are missing a `Next cLink`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as `.getElementByTagName()`.

The method you are looking for is `.getElementsByTagName()`, which returns a collection of html elements.

Also in your case the button element's inner html is:

```
<!-- react-text: 400 -->Process Path Group: <!-- /react-text --><!-- react-text: 401 -->ALL<!-- /react-text -->
```

and not just `ALL`

So, you could go for something like:

```
Set AvailableLinks = IE.document.getElementsByTagName("button")

For Each clink In AvailableLinks
    If clink.innerHTML = "<!-- react-text: 400 -->Process Path Group: <!-- /react-text --><!-- react-text: 401 -->ALL<!-- /react-text -->" Then
    clink.Click
    End If
Next clink
```

Or even simpler:

```
Set AvailableLinks = IE.document.getElementsByTagName("button")

For Each clink In AvailableLinks
    If clink.innerText = "Process Path Group: ALL" Then
    clink.Click
    End If
Next clink
```